# Backbone JS event does not trigger for dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have a Backbone View that renders an external Handlebars template (*.hbs). This view is rendered inside of another View where it is instantiated, essentially:

```
MainAppView
render: function() {
//load main layout
var childView = new ChildView();
}


ChildView

render: function() {
$('body').append(this.template(data));
}

template:

<ul id="someId">
<li><a> {{data}}</a></li>
</ul>

and an events hash in the childView like this:

events: {
  'click #someId li a' : 'doSomething'
}

doSomething: function() { event.preventDefault(); console.log("exit");}
```

That's the gist of it. The problem, the selector `#someId li a` does not work and it fails to perform `doSomething`

I verified the selector with jQuery, by binding the function doSomething in the Chrome console, that works fine.

I think I know why it doesn't work in Backbone though, the HBS template is rendered after delegateEvents is fired off when the ChildView is instantiated, which means there exist no elements by the selector I am using and hence nothing was bound. I tried prefixing with a body, but nah, did not work either.

What do I need to do?

Comment: `$('body').append(this.template(data));` and only instanciating `ChildView` looks odd.  The events are established with the `delegateEvents()` method right after initialization. DOM operations like `empty()` or `html()` might remove those listeners when called on parent nodes. Please add how you render `MainAppView`. Check if there are any of those calls before `render()`ing `ChildView`  the first time or again

Answer (score 4):

Your `ChildView` render method is rendering the contents of the view into the body rather than inside itself. You render should look something like this:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.append(this.template(data));
    $('body').append(this.$el);
}
```

The reason the `doSomething` function wasn't being called is because events in Backbone are delegated to the root element of the view (`view.el`). The following is basically what Backbone is doing under the hood:

```
'click #someId li a' : 'doSomething'
```

becomes

```
view.$el.on('click', '#someId li a', view.doSomething);
```

If you go and append the template content directly to the `body` instead of the view's el, the events will never be caught by the view and thus the callbacks aren't called.

Answer (score 2):

I think doSomething function is missing the parameter `event` so add the parameter:

```
doSomething: function(e) { e.preventDefault(); console.log("exit");}
```

Comment: Are you serious, you don't need to pass in an event argument to a function

Comment: @ParijatKalia you actually do. It only works in Chrome (maybe IE) because they have a global variable called event, that stores the last event. If you tried to run this code in Firefox it will throw and error that 'event' is undefined.

Comment: Humbled :) after all these years of JS programming, phew :)

Comment: I just edited my answer, it should work on every browser now, because we don't use the Chrome specific event global variable.